# Is calling one Service from different Activities through AsyncTask ok?

Tags: android, android-service, android-asynctask

I have a `Service` downloading data every second from a web server (This `Service` is launched from my main `Activity`). In my app there are other `Activity`s each of them needs to refresh their UI according to the data downloaded by the `Service`.

My idea is to give to each of my `Activity`s an `AsyncTask` which will retrieve a small amoumt of data from the `Service` every second. Then the `AsyncTask` will tell to the UI to update.

Until yesterday I was all doing through `AsyncTask`, but I read this morning on stackoverflow that retrieving data and giving it to several `Activity`s is more a `Service` job than an `AsyncTask` one.

So I came up with this (not-so-good-even-a-bit-crapy) solution because I can't find how to notify my `Activity`s when the data is retrieved by the `Service`.
I read about broadcast receiver, listener, intent... but can't figure out how I can make my `Activity`'s "subscribe" to this one service periodically.

Thanks for your help.

PS : is it ridiculous to code sample each of my keywords in my writing like that :) ?

PS2 : use case of my app is retrieving temperature, pressure etc... from web services and monitoring each of these quantities in a different Activity (I can't monitor them all in the same Activity).

Comment: Comment on your first "PS": Yeah, seems a little aggressive imo :)

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind for a future question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can be refreshed over activity from service thru Handler.

1. In service you can create getter & setter of the handler.
2. Set the handler of the activity when your activity starts that will make the service to have the handler of the activity which is currently visible.
3. Use this handler instance to notify about data to the activity.

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for handler.

Comment: Thanks Vineet Shukla. So I create an Handler with a timer and for example every 1000ms it will call the getter in the Service ? Am I getting this right ? If yes what is the difference with the AsyncTask I was talking about... apart from the obvious :).

Comment: Why are you using count down timer? When you come to the activity then set it's handler to the service so that your service has the handler of the current visible activity.

Comment: I think I miss some knowledge here sorry. For me a Handler is in a different thread and give you the ability to check periodically on something with a timer. Just like an AsyncTask with a loop in the doInBackGround. Of course you can use it only once in both cases without timer or loop. I do not understand how I can link the activity's handler with the Service in order to retrieve value from it periodically or each time the value is fetching from the web server.

Comment: you will send mag from handler when you have some data for the activity and you will receive this msg over activity. On getting the msg you can update your activity.

Comment: I post the solution that I think you describe to me, one last thing my handler had to be static to be called from the Service... there is no way around ?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I achieve what I want (Thanks to **Vineet Shukla**) :

In the Activity "ServiceConsumerActivity", add :

```
public static RefreshHandler mRefreshHandler;

class RefreshHandler extends Handler
{  
    @Override  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {  
        showServiceData(); //from which I call a method of the Service for getting the fetching value 
    }  
};
```

In the Service, add :

```
Message mMessage = new Message();
ServiceConsumerActivity.mRefreshHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
```

Comment: can you please write down showServiceData function as well. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's too old. Can't remember a thing about it.